# How to iterate and update circle radius based on each row value using D3 library?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm learning D3.js and,
I want to make three circles, one circle for one column, except the Date column,
and a slider (scrubber) based on time.

the final code should visualize the three circles in which their radius is changing over time (daily basis) and get bigger or smaller.
but the problem is that only one circle being created and no change in radius, same circle size whatever is the day,

I'm using Observablehq Notebook and D3 v5.

this is a sample of my data in CSV file:

```
Date,Messages in public channels,Messages in private channels,Messages in DMs
2020-02-26,5,2,10
2020-02-27,12,50,6
2020-02-28,9,11,5
2020-02-29,1,3,4
2020-03-01,53,1,45
2020-03-02,8,5,2
2020-03-03,2,3,0
```

I have this code :

```
//Data:-------------
data = d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("All-time.csv").text(), d3.autoType);
dates = {
  const text = await FileAttachment("All-time.csv").text();
  const parseDate = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  return d3.csvParse(text, (d => 
    parseDate(d.Date))
  )  
};
mssgPb = {
  const text = await FileAttachment("All-time.csv").text();
  return d3.csvParse(text, (d => +d["Messages in public channels"] )
  )  
}
mssgPv ={
  const text = await FileAttachment("All-time.csv").text();
  return d3.csvParse(text, (d => +d["Messages in private channels"] )
  )  
}
mssgDm ={
  const text = await FileAttachment("All-time.csv").text();
  return d3.csvParse(text, (d => +d["Messages in DMs"])
  )  
}
//Chart:-----------
bubbleChartEnd = {
  day;
  
  const svg = d3
    .create("svg")
    .attr('id', 'bubble-chart')
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .attr("font-size", 12)
    .attr("font-weight", 'bold')
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

 renderBubbleChart(svg, mssgDm, 'purple', 50, 50);
  renderBubbleChart(svg, mssgPb, 'red', 100, 100);
  renderBubbleChart(svg, mssgPv, 'blue', 50, 50);
 
  return svg.node();
}
//Scrubber:------------
viewof day = Scrubber(dates, {
  initial: dates.length,
  autoplay: false,
  delay: 1000,
  format: date => {var newFormat = d3.utcFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
  return newFormat(date)}
  })
//functions:------------
renderBubbleChart = (selection, data, color, x, y) => {
const renderData = data
.map((d, i) => {
      return circleComponent({
        r: [d],
        cx: x + i * 100,
        cy: y,
        fill: color,
        duration: 1000
      });
    })
  return render(selection , renderData );
}

circleComponent = ({
  key,
  r,
  cx,
  cy,
  fill
}) => {
  return {
    append: 'circle',
    key,
    r,
    cx,
    cy,
    fill
  };
}
```

your kind help, please.